# How to connect a path between 2 points in a grid using D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Well I've [made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVwCo.png) a grid and 2 dragable rectangles on the grid. I would like a path to be created between the 2 rectangles which always follows the grid(no diagonal). Also once the path has been created, it should automatically adjust if ether one of the rectangles is moved. Could someone suggest an approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with a [path string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths):

```
var s = 10        //grid size
var p0 = [10, 15] //start point
var p1 = [20, 25] //end point

var connectionPath = svg.append('path')
  .attr('d', [
    'M', p0[0]*s, p0[1]*s,  //put pen at start point
    'H', p1[0]*s,           //move pen horizontally
    'V', p1[1]*s            //move pen vertically
  ].join(' '))
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('stroke', '#000')
```

To adjust when the rectangles are dragged, update the `d` attribute each time one of the rectangles is dragged.

Comment: Thanks for the idea